# How to develop a Delete command through Behavior Driven Development?

Tags: bdd

I am trying to develop a Delete command through BDD that will simply delete an user from the database, given user_id as a parameter. What can be some possible behavioral tests that will drive me to write a proper implementation for the command?

Comment: Postulate that when you delete a particular user AND THEN list your users, that user DOESN'T appear. A deletion by itself has no observable effect, you need to describe at least two steps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some possible tests:

1. (Delete works) When `user_id` is in the database, if `delete(user_id)` is called, `user_id` will no longer be in the database
2. (Delete affects only one record) When `user_id` is in the database, and there are other users as well, if `delete(user_id)` is called, the other users will still be in the database
3. (Delete no-op) When `user_id` is not in the database, if `delete(user_id)` is called, `user_id` should still not be in the database (or maybe an exception gets thrown; depends on your spec)

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more thing, for steps such as 1, we have to do state verification right? (e.g., `assertEquals(getUserWithId(user_id), null))`. In many resources about introducing BDD, I have seen examples of doing behavior verification, but not much of state verification. Is it normal to mix state verification as well as behavior verification while doing BDD? I am asking because it seems to me we can't substitute one for the other.

Comment: @SamirHasan: Add a couple of examples and links to those resources and that's a great question. However, "One more thing ..." rarely makes a good comment.